# 新規EC2インスタンスにSSM経由でAnsibleを実行する方法

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, ansible

ssh 経由で実行するサーバー初期構築用の Ansible のレシピがあって
これまでローカルPCからssh経由で対象サーバーにレシピを実行していたんですが
このレシピをなるべく改変せずに ssh のかわりに SSM を使って実行する方法はあるでしょうか

---

セキュリティ要件のため管理はすべてSSM経由で行うことになり 
ローカルPCで ansible-playbook を実行するだけでは動きません

方法としては

1. SSM でEC2に入ってからレシピを git clone でもってきて
   ローカルホストに対して ansible を実行する

初期環境なので python, git, ansible が入っていないので手動でインストールする必要があり再現性が担保できない

2. aws cli には Run Command 
   (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/systems-manager/latest/userguide/walkthrough-cli.html)
   というのがあってSSM 経由でコマンドを実行できるみたいなのですが
   ansible で ssh のかわりにこの Run Command を使用するというのはできないでしょうか
3. python, git, ansible をインストールしてローカルに Ansible を実行する
   という１連のスクリプトを書いてそれを Run Command で呼べば可能ではあるのですが
   対象サーバーに ssh さえあれば何もインストールする必要がない Ansible のメリットが損なわれます

コストがかかるようであれば一時的に ssh をあけてもらって
レシピをいままでどおり実行した後閉じるということになるんですが
それも上長へ申請が必要なので、できるのであればSSMでansibleを実行する方法を知りたいです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> これまでローカルPCからssh経由で対象サーバーにレシピを実行していたんですが
>   このレシピをなるべく改変せずに ssh のかわりに SSM を使って実行する方法はあるでしょうか

最初に回答した通り、SSMは複数台や定期的に複数回実行することを目的としているので、初期構築という意味ではあまり適切とは思えません。
Ansibleは`ssh`をトンネルとして利用しManaged Nodeを制御します。しかしSSMはトンネルは提供せず、定型コマンドを実行するのみの機能となります。

---

> 対象サーバーに ssh さえあれば何もインストールする必要がない Ansible のメリットが損なわれます

勘違いされているようですが、AnsibleのManaged Nodeとして動作させるためには[`ssh`だけでなく`python`も必要と明記](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements)されています。初期環境で`python`が入っていないとのことなので、どの道パッケージのインストール処理が必要です。
なお、SSMはAnsibleのControl Nodeの役割を担うわけではありません。対象サーバーはControl Nodeとして[`ansible`のインストールも必要](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-node-requirements)です。

その上で、SSMを使用するのであれば[SSMエージェント](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html)のインストール処理も必要です。

---

`AWS-RunRemoteScript`を使用することで[Amazon S3 からのスクリプトの実行](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/systems-manager/latest/userguide/integration-remote-scripts.html#integration-s3)なんかは可能です。
ただし、SSMは複数台や定期的に複数回実行することを目的としているので、初期構築という意味ではあまり適切とは思えません。

ユーザーデータを使用すれば、[インスタンス起動時に実行](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)可能なため、そちらで初期構築することをお勧めします。

Comment: Ansibleの機能としてSSHの代わりにSSMを使うということが可能かどうか（＝既存レシピをそのまま流用できるか）をききたかったんですが、やはりSSMで入ってAnsibleの環境を整えた後、localhostを対象にレシピを実行する（ような１連のスクリプトをAWS-RunRemoteScriptなりユーザーデータなりで行う）しかない感じでしょうか

Comment: @KTI 論点が何で、どのような懸念をされているのかよくわかりませんでした。尋ねたい内容・答えてほしい内容を質問文に記載してください。

Comment: 申し訳ないです　質問整理し直しました　論点はAWSの機能ではなくAnsible側の機能です

Comment: これまで ManagedNode はローカルのPCでローカルにAnsible環境を作れば対象サーバーへのSSHができればレシピの実行はできていました。今後SSHができないので対象サーバー自身をManagedNodeにするしかなく、そのためにpythonやAnsibleをいれてローカルホストを対象にAnsibleを実行する必要があるので、それをしなくていい方法はないか（たとえばSSHコマンドの変わりにSSMで接続するAWSコマンドでおきかえるような機能がAnsibleにないか）がききたい内容でした。

Comment: >しかしSSMはトンネルは提供せず、定型コマンドを実行するのみ　おとなしくSSHをあけてもらうように申請してみます！

Answer (score 0):

AnsibleのPlaybookはYAMLで記述されますが、SSMで使用されるのはJSON形式での設定ファイルになるようなので、単純な流用は出来ないと思います。